# jQuery event blur function - how to DRY it up?

Tags: jquery, events, dry, blur

I'm using jQuery for an employee management form. 
This code works, but it is repetitive. Is there a better way to do this? 
I don't have a lot of experience with jQuery, so I appreciate any pointers you have.
The selectors reference inputs in the HTML.

```
$('#fname').blur(function(){    
var key = "name_first";
var value = $(this).val();
if ( value != _fname ){
    changeemp(key, value);
    _fname = value;
}
});
$('#lname').blur(function(){        
var key = "name_last";
var value = $(this).val();
if ( value != _lname ){
    changeemp(key, value);
    _lname = value;
}           
});
$('#initials').blur(function(){     
var key = "initials";
var value = $(this).val();
if ( value != _initials ){
    changeemp(key, value);
    _initials = value;
}               
});             
$('#email').blur(function(){        
var key = "email";
var value = $(this).val();
if ( value != _email ){
    changeemp(key, value);
    _email = value;
}               
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="fname"><span>First Name</span></label><br/>
<input type="text" id="fname" class="inputdata"><br/><br/>

<label for="lname">Last Name</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="lname" class="inputdata"><br/><br/>

<label for="initials">Displayed Initials</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="initials" class="inputdata"><br/><br/>

<label for="email">Email Address</label><br/>
<input type="email" id="email" class="inputdata"><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Can you also post the accompanying HTML? Also, where do the `_fname`, `_lname` etc variables come from?

Comment: _fname, _lname, etc are global vars.

Comment: where you declared the variables _email,_fname,_initials, _lname ??

Comment: Outside the (function($) {}) in my external .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be:

```
var blurInfos = [
{ id: '#fname', key: 'name_first', varName: '_fname'},
{ id: '#lname', key: 'name_last', varName: '_lname'},
{ id: '#initials', key: 'initials', varName: '_initials'}
];

var varContext = window;

var handleBlur = function (blurInfo) {
    $(blurInfo.id).blur(function(){    
        var key = blurInfo.key;
        var value = $(this).val();
        if ( value != varContext[blurInfo.varName] ){
            changeemp(key, value);
            varContext[blurInfo.varName] = value;
        }
    });
};

for (var i = 0; i < blurInfos.length; i++) {
    var blurInfo = blurInfos[i];
    handleBlur(blurInfo);
};
```

### Notes

- The code assumes the variables `_fname`, `_lname` etc. are in the global context (`window`). Otherwise the code has to be modified accordingly.

#### Edit

Updated answer, since it is considered to be bad practice defining `function`s in `for` loops

Answer (score 0):

Set the key as an attribute on the html elements or use the id to match values from an object in the format of 
{ {sId} : {sValue}, {sId} : {sValue} }. it would turn into something like this:

```
$('.inputdata').change(function()
{
   // this method should handle comparing and setting
   TryChangeEmp(this.id, this.value);
});

TryChangeEmp = function(sId, sVal)
{
   // where defaultValues is your default values in keyValue pair { sId : sValue }
   if (defaultValues[sId] != sVal) 
   {
      defaultValues[sId] = sVal; 
      /* whatever other processing */
   }
}
```

I also changed to use the change event, since this seems to fit your criteria better